# Filter elements on data-attribute instead of class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a simple method for filtering elements depending on their class. The user checks a checkbox and the jQuery does it's thing fine and turns off any element depending on the class. The line that turns off the element, and how the elements look is:

```
$('#ItemList div:not(.' + Filter + ')').hide();
<div class="1 2 3">asdf</div>
```

However I want to be able to use the data-xxxx attribute to do this instead of the class attribute, but I am having problems actually selecting the elements this way. What I have is below:

```
$("#ItemList div:not([data-filter'" + Filter + "'])").hide();
<div data-filter="1 2 3">asdf</div>
```

So, how do I go about selecting the element using the data-filter attribute instead of the class? The methods I have found on here are not working for me!
Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so James Allardice's reply did the trick. But has caused another issue that I probably should I said in the original post.

Each data-xxxx attribute can have a number of values, I need this filter to work so that if any one of the value shows up it will not hide the element.

```
$('#Filters input').change(function()
{
    $('#ItemList div').show();
    $('input').each(function()
    {
        var Checked;
        if(Checked = $(this).attr('checked'))
        {
            var Filter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $("#ItemList div:not([data-filter='" + Filter + "'])").hide();
        };
});

<div data-filter="1">1</div>
<div data-filter="1 3">1 3</div>
```

So for example if a checkbox with the following attribute is checked it will show both divs:

```
data-filter="1"
```

But if the attribute is like this it will only show the second:

```
data-filter="3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery filter function like this:

```
$("#ItemList div").filter(function()
    {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        var filterArr = attr.split(" ");
        return $.inArray(Filter, valArr) == -1;
    }
).hide();
```

I haven't tested this but it should work.
You can find the inArray documentation from the this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) and the documentation for the filter function from this [link](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 4):

You were close. You're just missing the `=` character:

```
$("#ItemList div:not([data-filter='" + Filter + "'])").hide();
//                               ^ You missed this
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Vy9du/).

Comment: Thats the one! Nice one, however I now have another problem, that I didn't count on. Shall update the job.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('[data-name=something]') or for not, jQuery('[data-name!=something]')

Check out the attribute selectors available here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/